# Use application.properties in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I'm trying to pick up some config from application.properties and then override it in the unit test. However, the unit test always sets the schemaPath property to `null`.

This is what I have:

`Service`:

```
@Service
public class XmlValidator {

    @Value("${schema.location}")
    private String schemaPath;

    public void validateXml(String fileName) {
        String schemaPath = null;
        if (fileName.contains("Reference")) {
            schemaPath = schemaPath;
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties and application-test.properties:

```
schema.location = /schema/Schema_Reference_0.1.xsd
```

Unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = XmlValidator.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:config/application-test.properties")
public class XmlValidatorTest {

    private XmlValidator validator = new XmlValidator();

    @Test
    public void testSchema() throws Exception {
        validator.validateXml("resources/xmlFile.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating a new XmlValidator. If you want the properties to be replaced you have to autowire the validator.

Comment: you are doing 
`private XmlValidator validator = new XmlValidator();`
it will not use spring to initialise validator. instead use 
```@Autowired 
private XmlValidator validator;```

if you use new XmlValidator(); the value will never be populated even in case of application, leave alone test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Your issue seems very simple to fix, and it may not have anything to do with the profiles. Check the following line

```
private XmlValidator validator = new XmlValidator();
```

This is not letting Spring autowire the spring bean as you're creating object by calling constructor. It should be done as below

```
@Autowired
private XmlValidator validator;
```

This will let Spring do it's magic and you'll get an injected bean.

## Profile related issue

`application-test.properties` will be picked up only when `test` profile is active.

Check the active profiles printed in logs when test starts. It should show something like below

```
The following profiles are active: test,dev,local
```

Where `test, dev, local` are profiles that your spring app uses. If these profiles are active then following properties files will be picked up by spring.

```
application-test.properties
application-dev.properties
application-local.properties
#Similarly *.yml files

#Following are unconditional
bootstrap.properties
application.properties
```

Check this documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

It would probably be easier to put this test related properties in `src/test/resources/application.properties` without profile suffix. If you do require profile `test` then you would have to activate it by using either environment variables or by modifying `application.properties` file using following properties

```
spring.profiles.include=test
or
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Comment: I tried renaming to application.properties but still same result

Comment: :) well I think I went overboard with a simple issue, you're using `XmlValidator = new XmlValidator()` this does not allow Spring to create bean. It should be wired by Spring check  my answer, edited.

Answer (score 0):

application.properties file content should be:

```
schema.location=/schema/Schema_Reference_0.1.xsd
```

as you can see no spaces near the '=' sign

It could be the application.properties file used in application not visible in text context. You should check this either.

Comment: white space won't affect the value of the property